# SQLite: How Do I Reference Tables In Another SQLite Database?

Tags: database, sqlite, datagrip

I'm currently working with SQLite within DataGrip IDE. I am trying to reference another .sqlite database using the *"attach database"* method that every google search seems to bring up.

Attached are 2 screenshots, **SCREENSHOT 1** shows the alias *sandbox1* was created without a hitch, and the IDE seems to recognize *sandbox1* as shown in the first screenshot.

[image: SCREENSHOT 1]

[image: SCREENSHOT 2]

**Problem Point:** Shown in screenshot 2, after the dot operator I was expecting tables (outlined in red) in Database1 ("sandbox_DB1.sqlite") to populate the box area but but the alias "sandbox1" doesn't seem to be attached to actual database1.

Comment: This database viewer program might not be smart enough to look up table names in attached databases for auto-complete. Just type them in manually?

Comment: That should work. After you perform 'attach database' you should see it under 'main' in database explorer. Please refresh second data source. Also which IDE and driver versions do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to type manually? You done the right thing but seems that the the DB viewer doesn't work fine for creating the dropdown. For SQLite I am using https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please go to data source properties -> Options tab -> enable 'Single session mode' and try again.